# Yii2 Dependent Dropdown Data Not Show

Tags: php, yii2

I am using [krajee yii2 depdrop](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-depdrop) in my form. I follow the instruction and my data still not show on depdrop.

This is my _form.php code :

```
    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'id_trayek')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Trayek::find()->all(), 'id_trayek', 'nama_trayek'),
        'language' => 'en',
        'theme' => Select2::THEME_KRAJEE,
        'options' => ['id' => 'id_trayek', 'placeholder' => '-- Pilih Trayek --', 'class' => 'form-control'],
    ]); ?>

    <?php
        echo $form->field($model, 'no_bus')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
            'type'=>DepDrop::TYPE_SELECT2,
            'options' => ['id'=>'no_bus', 'class'=>'form-control'],
            'pluginOptions'=>[
                'depends'=>['id_trayek'],
                'placeholder' => '-- Pilih Bus --',
                'url' => Url::to(['/surat-jalan/bus'])
            ]
        ]);
    ?>
```

This is my controller for depdrop url :

```
    public function actionBus() {
        $out = [];
        if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
            $id_trayek = end($_POST['depdrop_parents']);
            $jenis_bus = Trayek::find()->select('jenis_bus')->andWhere(['id_trayek'=>$id_trayek]);
            $list = Bus::find()->andWhere(['jenis_bus'=>$jenis_bus])->asArray()->all();
            $selected  = null;
            if ($id_trayek != null && count($list) > 0) {
                $selected = '';
                foreach ($list as $i => $bus) {
                    $out[] = ['no_bus' => $bus['no_bus'], 'no_bus' => $bus['no_bus']];
                }

                echo Json::encode(['output' => $out, 'selected'=>$selected]);
                return;
            }
        }
        echo Json::encode(['output' => '', 'selected'=>'']);
    }
```

in console, I found JSON response is OK and error : TypeError: id is undefined on file dependendent-dropdown.js (line 39, col 49)

Error from console
[image: Error from console]

Comment: it's a javascript error, yet you haven't pasted your javascript. could you?

Comment: you mean dependent-dropdown.js file or I must paste some javascript on my code?? because there is no additional javascript on depdrop documentation..

Comment: ok lets see the dropdown js

Comment: you want to see inside dropdown js or what?? I am sorry if my english bad. the dropdown js file is pure from depdrop repository and I never change the js file, and the js file is loaded.

Comment: yes, but we can see what variable it will be looking for, and figure out why it hasn't been passed to it

Comment: sorry dude, its my mistake, I change the default controller value..
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is not correct:

```
$out[] = ['no_bus' => $bus['no_bus'], 'no_bus' => $bus['no_bus']];
```

Dependent dropdown *requires* the first array element to be `id` and the second one to be `name`. Change to this:

```
$out[] = ['id' => $bus['no_bus'], 'name' => $bus['no_bus']];
```

Comment: thanks man, its working, I think id & name is just example, so I change to my db field..